# How to make default kind of new kotlin file to class?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

There is kotlin file by default, but I want to make a class as default kind. Just like in Java. I hate to swith it to class every time I want to make new class file.

[image]

Comment: You can press the down arrow on the keyboard after typing the class name, to switch it from File to Class quickly.

Comment: If you forget to switch it to class, then it shows up as a file in the list, with a .kt extension that is visible. It all works, but doesn't appear with the class icon as it should. I can't find a way to correct that either.

Comment: @JimLeask If you have created a kotlin file but intended to create a class, you just do the following: create a class with a name corresponding to file's name inside that empty file. Boom, icon will change and everything would be fine) (Assuming you use Idea/Android studio)

Comment: No, I have added the class inside these files, the the icon remains a file, with the .kt extension. I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Ah - turns out the class symbol in the list is only there if the file contains 'class' as the very first item (after imports). If you have anything else, like a 'data class', 'interface',  or even 'private const', then the icon for the file reverts to the file icon instead of class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. You can, however, create own file template (preferences -> editor -> file and code templates)

Now just select the package in Project view and use **New...** action (not **Kotlin File/Class** that you used before). Popup will appear where you can type characters to select desired template

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[You can update File templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLNQV.png)

update `Kotlin File` to `kotlin Class`contents,`Kotlin File` tab we don't use it most of the time.

Than. new Kotlin File tab = new Kotlin Class tab.

It's stupid, but it works for me.This saves time in choosing Class by arrow.